# Solr group query records mismatch

Tags: solr

I fired a group query in solr, below is my query

> http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=to_domain:"gmail.com"+AND+hostname:"servername"+AND+log_date:[2011-12-08T00:00:00Z+TO+2011-12-10T23:59%:9Z]&group=true&group.field=id&group.limit=10&rows=100000

The query is fired successfully and I get the following in the result

```
<int name="matches">71133</int>
```

The problem is that now when I count the groupValue sections it comes to 70311

Any ideas why this difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<int name="matches">71133</int>` gives you the total number of records and not the group count.

use [group.ngroups=true](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters) in the request parameters to provide you the number of groups in the response.